# Prove that if $A,B\unlhd G, A\cap B = ${$e$}$\rightarrow \forall a\in A $ and $\forall b\in B $ ab=ba

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I tried to prove this statement, and I would like to have some input if it's complete:

Consider:

$(aba^{-1})b^{-1} = b_1b^{-1} \in B$ $ $    (because $B\unlhd G$)

$a(ba^{-1}b^{-1}) = aa_1 \in A$ $ $    (because $A\unlhd G$)

Hence: $b_1b^{-1} = aa_1 = e$ $ $    (because $A\cap B = ${$e$})

This gives us: $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e \rightarrow ab(ba)^{-1}=e \rightarrow ab = ba$

Comment: You should explain all of your statements.  For example, since $B$ is normal in $G$, $aba^{-1}\in B$.  Therefore, there exists $b_1\in B$ such that $aba^{-1}=b_1$.  Moreover, you say $b_1b^{-1}=aa_1=e$.  It would be better to say that since $b_1b^{-1}=aa_1$ is in $B$ and $A$, so $b_1b^{-1}\in A\cap B=\{e\}$, so $b_1b^{-1}=e$.

Comment: Thanks, added explanations on each line (You're right, I should've done this before)

Comment: Are you two doing the same homework, or passing the same exam? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162605/proving-that-hk-kh

Comment: I don't know :)